# Random walk on infinite graph with zero probability of leaving subgraph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-variables, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an graph which is locally finite (every vertex has only finitely many edges - but there may be infinitely many vertices), and connected. Let $X_n$ be a random walk on $G$ that follows the transition probabilities induced by the edge weights of $G$.

Is it possible to find a $G$ such that there exists a nonempty $U \subseteq V$ such that if we let $W$ be the subgraph of $G$ induced by the vertices $V \setminus U$, then $W$ is connected and we have that for any $w \in W$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P_w(X_n \in W | X_{n-1} \in W) = 1$ ?

($P_w$ denotes that $X_0 = w$)

Edit: Made some mistakes earlier. Corrected to indicate that the walk starts in $W$ and that both $W$ and $G$ are connected.

Comment: Do you indicate by $P_u$ the stationary distribution? If not, that cannot hold for all $n$, right? (Consider $n^*$ to be the first time $X_n$ enters $W$. Then $X_{n^*+1}$ has by definition a non-zero chance to leave $W$, by "coming back whence it comes" -- or what did I miss?)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake $P_u$ is the probability with respect to starting the walk at $u \in W$

Comment: Then, you may require the graph to be connected, since otherwise the answer is trivially "yes" (take $U$ to be a non-empty connected component, and $W$ another.)

Comment: Yes, made both edits just now. Thanks so much!

Comment: And if the graph is connected then the answer is trivially "no".

Comment: Is it still no if I am interested in the limit of the probability as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: No, in an irreducible Markov chain, the process will eventually exit any finite proper subset of the state space. It may or may not be guaranteed to return, depending on various problem specifics.

Comment: $W$ can be infinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P_w(X_n \in W | X_{n-1} \in W) = 1
$$
is to take a graph whose random walk Markov chain is transient.

For instance, let $G$ be an infinite binary tree, and let $W$ be one of the branches from the root. Then with probability $1$ the random walk only returns to the root a finite number of times, so in the limit as $n \to \infty$ the probability of the random walk leaving $W$ is $0$.